# Divinity Origin Sin 2 - Alexander Boss Fight

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

Playing through on normal.

My level 7 party is as follows

Pyro
Elementalist/Healer
Fighter (1h + shield)
Ranger

Most fights in the game have been moderately challenging and often take more than one attempt.  This one is different. I considered getting to level 8 and even things out but there isn't any experience left to get on the island.

I've tried coming in the front door (epic fail) and from the right side (after purging the shriekers).

I can make it to the worm but things continue sharply down hill at that point.

Am I missing something fundamental?  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you only have 3 people, having a fourth would have been a big bonus. Are you focusing certain people down and CCing where appropriate? Are you paying attention to weaknesses of enemies? The Voidworm will fight everyone, and the magisters tend to go after it as well so you could take that time to heal up.

Answer (score 2):

The fight is not easy but a party of your level should be enough. Without knowing much of your playstyle during that fight, my only advice would be to play low : when the worm appears, ignore him, stay away from him, and attack the magisters (yeah, even if your said that "you have to team up against the greater ennemy"). They will mostly attack the worm so you can use that time to effectively heal your party and weaken the magisters without getting to much retribution for it.

Answer (score 1):

The trick that worked for me was initially pulling the fight from the main courtyard to the side one:

Leave most of your group ear the side entry (one that would take you to the wall above Alexander) and get one mobile character (with "Spread your Wings" or "Tactical Retreat") on the wall, so you will be spotted by Alexander. When the fight will start, quickly retreat to the rest of your group: enemies will now have to be approach you one-by one using the narrow passage, which you can conveniently set on fire (although you can still be shot at by the archer originally sitting on nearby wall).

When the worm will spawn ignore it and focus on killing the soldiers first (don't worry - magisters would betray you just as easy) while they will be busy fighting the voidspawn.

Answer (score 1):

Using the teleport gloves, I "abducted" the thing that stands by Alexander. I stood at the front gate, teleported them to the steps and killed them.

I tried doing the same on Alexander, but that triggered the main fight. I was out of range of the archer and polymorph guy though, so it was simple until the worm showed up. At that point, I gathered everyone at the top of the stairs, teleported Alexander to the worm and let them fight it out. Then I went back and faced the range guys separately.